# How to Fix WordPress Posts Returning 404 Error?

Tags: wordpress

using cpanel.

I have tried this:

1. Go to Settings » Permalinks, and simply click on Save Changes button.
2. changing my .htaccess to 666

> ```
> > # BEGIN WordPress
> >     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> >     RewriteEngine On
> >     RewriteBase /
> >     RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
> >     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> >     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> >     RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
> >     </IfModule>
> >     # END WordPress
> ```

It's still not working.

Comment: set permission on .htaccess file 644 and save permalink by select post name and update your settings. Also try to access your page also, is it working.

Comment: @dineshkashera still not working..

Comment: Can you access any pages ?

Comment: i can access all pages using plain `website.com/?page_id=1005`

Comment: is it wamp server?

Comment: no its nginx in cpanel

Answer (score 0):

- Login to your server using FTP, and modify the .htaccess file which is located in the same location where folders like /wp-content/ and /wp-includes/ are located.
- The easiest thing you can do is to temporarily make the file writeable by changing the permissions to 666. Then repeat the original solution.
- Don’t forget to change the permissions back to 660. You can also manually add this code in your .htaccess file.

**Case 2 :**

- Login to your server using FTP, take backup of .htaccess and remove the .htaccess file or you can rename htaccess.
- Login to admin dashboard and update permalinks.

[How to update permalinks?](https://www.silocreativo.com/en/how-to-update-permalinks-in-wordpress/)

Answer (score 0):

Permalinks require mod_rewrite on webserver and should work after you click Save button on Settings > Permalinks screen from WP admin dashboard.

Due to various plugins or updates, the permalinks structure can sometimes get broken and 404 pages are shown on previously working URLs. You can Save permalinks again from backend.

There's also an automated fix by adding this code to index.php :

```
            if (is_404())   
        {
        global $wp_query;
        $page_slug = $wp_query->query_vars['name'];
        if ($page_slug) 
            { 
            $page = get_page_by_path($page_slug);
            if ($page) $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(true);
            }
        }
```